# What is the name of this chord? F# A D G D E

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory

I'm looking for the name of this chord: F# A D G D E

I have basic knowledge of chords but I can't figure out this one.

[image]

Comment: Some context would be useful in answering.  What chords precede and follow the chord in question?

Answer (score 1):

The basic triad seems like D major, with D F# and A. Add to that a 4 (G) and a 9 (E) it can be called D add 4 add 9. That's not to say 4+9=13, so it's D13, 'cos it's not.

Answer (score 1):

With such an open chord, it may come down to what key you're in. It could be called a D/F#, an Em7/F#, or a F#m7#5(b9)... there are lots of Jazz options...

Answer (score 1):

With a chord like this, it's pretty ambiguous, and it depends how it's functioning in context.

My guess would be that it's used as a convenient way to walk up from an Em to a G in an understated way without a fairly "neutral" sounding chord with good voice leading, in which case, it doesn't really matter what you call it, but the most descriptive way would be "Dsus over F#".  The "sus" is ambiguous because it doesn't specify sus2, sus4, (in this case it's both) but since it doesn't really matter in this context (either would behave the the same) then leaving it unspecified is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Chord name : F# Minor, Flat 9th +5

Degree : 1,b3,#5,b7,b9

Notes : F#,A,D,E,G